# How can i remove the key which contain the value white space in PHP, Laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, trim, explode

```
public function store(Request $request)
{  

    $article = Article::create($request->only(['content']));

    $categories = explode(",",$request->get('categories'));
    $category_ids =[];


    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $category_db = Category::where('name', trim($category))->firstOrCreate(['name'=> trim($category)]);
        $category_ids [] = $category_db->id;
    }

    $article->category()->attach($category_ids);
    return response("Successfully Added to Database");
}
```

[In the end there is no comma and no issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPXBj.jpg)
and  [in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsSSC.jpg) everything is fine

Now problem is that when i put a [comma in the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAB40.jpg) there is a cell created in the [database with whitespace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05mrp.jpg)

I know why this happening. The last key of the exploded array containing value is whitespace. But i want to omit or leave that empty key. How can i do that?

Comment: `if ('' == trim($category)) SKIP`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `array_filter()` which will remove all empty keys from the array. So here is the code you should use:

```
$categories = array_filter(explode(",",$request->get('categories')));
```